# High publish latency with AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-sns

I'm seeing some occasional latency spikes in a production env (up to 7 seconds) when publishing messages to SNS from EC2. According to datadog APM, the bottleneck is the call to `SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int)` which happens somewhere deep in the publish call. When looking at the sdk metrics in cloudwatch, the APICallDuration and ServiceCallDuration correlate with the numbers in datadog (> 6 seconds).

I'm using a r6a.2xlarge EC2 instance which runs in the same region as SNS (us-east-1)

I'm also using the SNS Java sync client and I'm creating it as follows

```
  private val metricsPublisher = CloudWatchMetricPublisher
    .builder()
    .cloudWatchClient(
      CloudWatchAsyncClient
        .builder()
        .httpClientBuilder(
          NettyNioAsyncHttpClient
            .builder()
        )
        .build()
    )
    .build()

  protected val client: SnsClient = SnsClient.builder
    .endpointOverride(URI.create(endpoint))
    .region(region)
    .overrideConfiguration(
      ClientOverrideConfiguration
        .builder()
        .addMetricPublisher(metricsPublisher)
        .build()
    )
    .build()
```

Any suggestions on possible fixes/mitigations?

Comment: Suggest support ticket to AWS with supporting diagnostics.